# How to copy a graph in JUNG 2.0 framework?

Tags: java, frameworks, graph, jung

in JUNG 1.7.6 there was the function copy() for this purpose (myGraph.copy()), but in JUNG 2.0 this function does not exist anymore. I could not find any other possibility to create a copy of a graph object. I would be very glad if someone could help me. A workaround would be nice, too.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Code below with generics, so you should replace `V` and `E` with `String` for your `Graph<String, String>`.

```
    Graph<V, E> src;
    Graph<V, E> dest;

    for (V v : src.getVertices())
        dest.addVertex(v);

    for (E e : src.getEdges())
        dest.addEdge(e, src.getIncidentVertices(e));
```

Comment: This is basically correct, but one nitpick and one enhancement: (1) you should not replace V,E with String, but with the types of your graph (and if you create your own static method you won't even need or want to do that).  (2) If you know a priori that all of your vertices have incident edges, and you're using the Graph classes that JUNG provides, you can leave out the first loop; addEdge will add the incident edges if they are not present.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the graph manually by iterating over all vertices and all edges and adding them to a new graph. See [getVertices()](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/Hypergraph.html#getVertices%28%29) in the API

Comment: If I have a Graph<String, String> the function getVertices() returns a Collection<String> with the vertices. The function getEdges() returns a Collection<String> with the edge ids, but I don't get the vertices which are connected by this edge... the only way I found to see which vertices are connected by a specific edge is to print the graph.toString() method...

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple copy of vertices & edges,
that would create a new Graph, but the objects inside will be passed by reference so you could use this cloning library https://code.google.com/p/cloning/

and do a deep copy:

```
Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
Graph<V, E> clonedGraph = cloner.deepClone(graph);
```