# what's the best way to clone a graph in Jung?

Tags: java, jung, jung2

the title pretty much sums it all -

I'm using Jung as my graph model and I want to clone my graphs. is there a best-practice for this?

thanks

Comment: It is already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470213/how-to-copy-a-graph-in-jung-2-0-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a simple copy of vertices & edges:

```
Graph<V, E> src;
Graph<V, E> dest;

for (V v : src.getVertices())
    dest.addVertex(v);

for (E e : src.getEdges())
    dest.addEdge(e, src.getIncidentVertices(e));
```

that would create a new Graph, but the objects inside will be passed by reference
so you could use this cloning library
https://code.google.com/p/cloning/

and do a deep copy:

```
Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
Graph<V, E> clonedGraph = cloner.deepClone(graph);
```